# Will empty properties of a bean be inserted to MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I am totally a newbie on Mongo. Please correct me if I am wrong. I would like to insert datas to MongoDB and I am using SpringData . So , I have one bean as follow..

```
@Document(collection = "myBean")
public class myBean {
@Id private String id;
// ... another properties
}
```

I noticed that when I inserted a bean without initialize some properties. I didn't see these fields in my collection of MongoDB. I think this shouldn't because when I inserted into MySQL DB , some fields can define default values. That fines but if I use MongoDB , am I need to define every properties of a bean to insert into collection ?

If I have hundreds of properties in a bean , how should I do ? Am I need to define some values or to use with default constructor to initialize them ?

Please somebody give me some suggestions for this. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has no default values for fields which is different to MySQL - you can find that two documents can have very different structures even in same collection.

Normally, spring-data-mongodb won't save field that is object type and with null value. This depends on the behavior of certain converter. So, you should initialize those fields in constructor or somewhere if you want to save the default values into MongoDB.